# Google Streetview Images API

Tags: api, google-maps

Is there an API available for grabbing Google Streetview images at a particular location (and direction)?  I see that its possible to get and position the Flash control, but I'd prefer something that just gave me a JPEG (or some other bitmap format).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the [Static Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/). <strike>Unfortunately, they haven't [finished](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=397) the work on having a static Street View map</strike> (The [Static Street View API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/streetview/) is now available). As comments 4 and 5 indicate, you may be able to get the thumbnail images used for Street View (though you may have to actually have Google load that particular image before being able to grab it and potentially cache it yourself). Other than that, you're stuck with the Flash control.

You may be able to have a service on the backend that essentially takes a screen cap of the Flash control and caches it, but that's a bit hackish.

Answer (score 4):

The static images aren't officially available, but you can grab the tiles and thumbnails using the same API that Google's Streetview flash application uses.

I wrote about the technique here:

http://jamiethompson.co.uk/web/2010/05/15/google-streetview-static-api/

Answer (score 1):

Google now offers a Street View Image API that serves this purpose:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/streetview/

Note that accessing Street View imagery through any means other than documented public APIs (like the Street View Image API and the JavaScript Maps APIs) is not permitted by the Maps API Terms of Service, and could result in requests for that imagery by your site being blocked by Google.

Many thanks,

Thor.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html#Streetview).

Here is the [reference documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GStreetviewPanorama).

Check out the [Google samples](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/demogallery.html?searchquery=street).

I believe that this [example](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/streetview/angletowardsbuilding.html) is what you are looking for.

Also, you will need to register for the [Google Maps API key](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/signup.html).